# HttpModule's BeginRequest alternate in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, orchardcms, httpmodule, actionfilterattribute

I have a HttpModule in my solution project (i am working in Orchard CMS). That module is used to rewrite the media urls to direct them to cdn.
I hooked two events:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        if (RewriteMediaEnable)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
            application.PostRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute);
        }
    }
```

Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute reads all the response generated, takes it chunk by chunk, and rewrites every media url found for CDN.
During chunking, some urls might miss the rewriting due to cutting between two chunks. For those Urls i have BeginRequest event.
It executes for individual media requests, so i can rewrite each remaining media request which got missed.

Now I want to remove this functionality from HttpModule and implement it in a Filter in my custom Orchard module. I have implemented IActionFilter and hooked to OnActionExecuted event.
It executes one time and in ActionExecutedContext i get the whole html page as response. So i implemented chunk by chunk rewriting here.

Now i want to catch all the remaining media urls that my rewriting missed during chunking. Apparently IActionFilter should be catching all the individual media request like BeginRequest, but it is not happening.

Is there any alternate for BeginRequest in MVC filters? OR how can i catch individual media requests?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wrote correctly, but it seems like your code is failing across chunk boundaries. Wouldn't that be the first problem to fix?

Comment: Thanks for the input Bertrand, i had handled the chunk boundaries case. It was some lack of knowledge/information on my side. There was web.config under 'Media' folder which had a StaticFileHandler/StaticFileModule to handle the individual media requests before they enter in the pipeline. That's why i was not getting any media requests in my ActionFilter.